# Prevent Firebase Database (or Auth) from functioning if APK SHA does not match SHA in Firebase console?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Scenario:** A user can take my APK, decompile it, change code, and run it. What would prevent them from changing perfectly valid calls to my Firebase Realtime Database but, pushing nonsense data instead? Or doing something malicious? Note, this doesn't concern **read/write rules**, as the DB nodes they are reading/writing would be allowed, but the modified code would simply be performing these actions in a way not desired to be received by the database under normal circumstances.

I feel like the SHA-1 fingerprint in my Project Settings in Firebase console would be the answer to prevent any improperly-signed APKs from accessing Firebase, right?

[image]

I've added by DEBUG SHA-1 to it and tried two things:

1. I did **not** download the newly updated google-services.json, ran my app anyway with DEBUG signing
2. I compiled a RELEASE version of my app and ran it (different signing obviously)

Both circumstances, Firebase Database **still functioned**...?
So what is the point of the SHA fingerprint? How do I basically toggle the setting of "if this APK isn't signed properly, do not access the database"?

Comment: Preventing someone from writing malicious data **does** concern security rules.  That's the reason why they exist.  SHA-1 isn't really going to help you lock that down, as there i is a public REST API that anyone on the internet can use to read and write things.  SHA-1 concerns auth only.

Comment: How would rules prevent someone from, for example, onClick() spamming 100 messages to a chat conversation whereas the code client-side would never allow that. Or, something like uncoupling some otherwise expected batch-writes in a single updateChildren() call on a node. It's not necessarily "malicious" code but rather, altering expected, rule-permitted normal behavior in a botting sort of way.

Comment: I suggest doing some web searches to discover common solutions to specific constraints you want to apply.  If you have a specific question about a specific contraint that you're trying to implement, post a question that explains that specific issue.

Comment: Here's one that seems problematic. I have a /rooms/ node with Room objects in it. When a User joins a Room, I would like to add the UID of the User to the "joinedMembers" list of the Room, for example. This means, in the DB rules, the user will have WRITE access to the "joinedMembers" list of Room nodes at least. What is preventing a user from modifying the APK to instead of adding their UID when this code executes, they add someone else's UID? Or just nonsense numbers?

Comment: Your security rules will prevent this, according to your specification. I recommend learning about them and start getting experience writing them.  Nothing is going to write these rules for you.

Comment: I know, if only there was a place to ask about such a thing...

Comment: People ask all the time about specific rules that they've written about specific security requirements that they have.  I suggest you do the same.  No one is going to surface security rules from thin air, not knowing the specific security constraints you're trying to address.  Those questions will get closed as "needs details or clarity".